# Node Js findByIdAndUpdate function not updating in db

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular2-routing

Im updating products based on its id in nodejs by creating API and calling them in angular 2 services.

**routes/products.js**

```
router.post('/:id', function(req, res, next) {

Products.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
if(err){
    res.json({success: false, msg:'Failed updating products'});
  } else {
    res.json({success: true, msg:'success updating products'});

  }
});
});
```

This is how im passing in postman: POST request

```
{
"id":"596df0ffcb429a586ef6c0bf",
"category_id": "596ddb165314d15618795826",
"product_name":"Laysssss masala",
"product_price":5,
"product_image":"image1ddd",
"product_desc":"Yummyddsd",
"product_status":"Activedddd"
}
```

Products seem to be saved in DB.

The same when i call in services under angular  and try in browser, i get "Product updated successfully" in broswer , but not reflecting in DB.

**component.ts**

```
onSaveConfirm(event) {
if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to save?')) {
 // var prodId = event.newData['_id']
  //console.log(event.newData)
  this.productService.productUpdate(event.newData).subscribe(data => {
    if (data.success) {
      console.log('Edited success')
      this.flashMessage.show('Product updated successfully', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000 });
      this.router.navigate(['/category-items']);
    } else {
      console.log('failure edited...')
      this.flashMessage.show('Something went wrong', { cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000 });
      this.router.navigate(['/category-items']);
    }
  });
  event.confirm.resolve(event.newData);
} else {
  event.confirm.reject();
}

}
```

**product.service.ts**

```
 productUpdate(products) {
var prodId = products['_id'];
console.log(products)
let prodUrl = "http://localhost:8080/products/" + prodId
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
let prodIdObj = JSON.stringify({ products: products })
return this.http.post(prodUrl, prodIdObj, { headers: headers })
  .map((response: Response) => response.json())
  .do(data => JSON.stringify(data))
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `data` in component.ts?

Comment: data has...Object {success: true, msg: "success updating products"}

Comment: any suggestions on this @Bhavana

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem here:

In `product.service.ts`:

```
productUpdate(products) {
//skipped
let prodUrl = "http://localhost:8080/products/" + prodId
//skipped
}
```

and `products.js`

```
router.post('/:id', function(req, res, next) {

    Products.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function (err, post) {
       if(err){
           res.json({success: false, msg:'Failed updating products'});
       } else {
       res.json({success: true, msg:'success updating products'});

       }
   });
});
```

change it to:

```
router.post('products/:id', function(req, res, next) {

    //do something
});
```

Comment: The URL is correct @Burdy, its routes/products.js and products.js file has http post for '/ (followed by something)' ... So I believe that's right !